# Como obtengo la versión de mi publicación con Visual Studio Community 2017 ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio

cada vez que publique quiero que se me vea la versión, no quiero usar un Label cada vez que publique modificar lo eso no, donde se ve el cuadro rojo es donde tengo un Label osea que el Label se modifique con la versión 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok para obtener tu version lo obtienes mediante:

```
public void setLabelVersion(){
 LabelVersion.Text = string.Format("TU aplicacion- v{0}",
        ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString(4));
}
```

Listo.